# Merge two dataframes based on date column and Id column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have two data frames `df` and `df1`, I want to merge based on the date also based on Id column,

`df` looks like

| arrival | input_fid |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 719 |
| 02-01-2021 | 719 |
| 02-01-2021 | 599 |
| 02-01-2021 | 599 |
| 02-01-2021 | 479 |
| 01-01-2021 | 359 |
| 04-01-2021 | 359 |

`df1` looks like

| date | input_fid | prcp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02-01-2021 | 479 | 0.44 |
| 01-01-2021 | 359 | 0.14 |
| 02-01-2021 | 599 | 0.33 |
| 03-01-2021 | 599 | 0.24 |
| 02-01-2021 | 719 | 0.08 |
| 01-01-2021 | 719 | 0.02 |
| 04-01-2021 | 359 | 0.10 |

The expected result is,

| arrival | input_fid | prcp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 719 | 0.02 |
| 02-01-2021 | 719 | 0.08 |
| 02-01-2021 | 599 | 0.33 |
| 04-01-2021 | 359 | 0.10 |
| 02-01-2021 | 479 | 0.10 |
| 01-01-2021 | 359 | 0.14 |
| 04-01-2021 | 359 | 0.10 |

I am not sure how to get that using two different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge_df = pd.merge(df1 , df2,  how='inner', left_on=['arrival','input_fid'], right_on = ['arrival','input_fid'])`